# Advice needed on using mobile technology with a .Net application

Tags: asp.net, mobile

The existing application is where workmen enter data on their PDAs and at the end of the day synchronise the data collected with a local database on a workstation.
Overnight a scheduled job synchronises that data with that of a centralised database at HQ.
The database is Access and the mobile uses a technology call Visual CE, which I had not heard of before.

The company I work for wants to replace this application with a .Net solution.
I have no experience with mobile technology. There do not seem to be many books in the subject in relation to .Net. When I Google for it there seems to be nothing in version 4.
So where do I start?
Should I stay with Visual CE on the PDAs or should I rewrite that?

Comment: What OS do the PDA's run? Is it windows CE? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_CE ) If so, I believe they can run software written using the .Net Compact Framework.

Comment: Thank you for that. Yes we use Windows CE. When I look for information on .Net Compact Framework it looks like it is not used anymore for new application development.